# javascript nodeType is 1 no matter what?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to find all text nodes on the page using jquery. But no matter what element I select, the nodeType is always 1:

```
$.each($('*'), function(index, el) { console.log(el.nodeType) });
```

Which resulted in nothing but "1" being output in the console. And to prove there is a "text node" on the page:

```
$('p:first').html()
=> "
            I'm text
          "

$('p:first')[0].nodeType
=> 1
```

What am I missing here? I'm using safari 5.0.4. I get the same result in firefox 3.6.12.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery will only select element nodes.

`$('p:first')` actually selects the first `<p>` element. To access the contained text node, you would need to access `firstChild` at the DOM node:

```
alert($('p:first')[0].nodeName) // alerts P                 <-- element node
alert($('p:first')[0].firstChild.nodeName) // alerts #text  <-- text node
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/pFkzm/)

Maybe you also have a misunderstanding: Elements containing text are not text nodes. Every element you create with tags `<..>` is an element node.

Example:

```
<p>
  Foo
  <span>Bar</span>
  Baz
</p>
```

The *element node* `<p>` has three children: Two *text nodes*, containing the text `Foo` and `Baz`, and an *element node* `<span>` which itself has a *text node* as child, containing `Bar`.

Comment: That's true. The whole premise of jQuery is using CSS-like selectors to select elements.

Comment: @Binary Logic Here is another answer, which describes how to find all text nodes with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery/4399718#4399718